# why ax.transData.transform([0.5, 0.5]) and ax.transAxes.transform([0.5, 0.5]) give the same result when ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i+1)?

Tags: matplotlib

I was reading [Data coordinates and Axes coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html)

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i, label in enumerate(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i+1)
    print(ax.transData.transform([0.5, 0.5]))
    print(ax.transAxes.transform([0.5, 0.5]))
    # why the two print the same result? 
    
    ax.text(0.1, 0.5, label, transform=ax.transAxes,
            fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')
    # transform=ax.transAxes replaced by transform=ax.transData the picture remains same 
plt.show()
```

I suppose that when `ax` created by `fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i+1)`, these `ax` have different coordinate in their parent figure, so `ax.transData` should defer from `ax.transAxes` when passed the same args, but the result perplexed me.

Comment: Because the default data limits are 0,1.  Change them to -10,10 and you will see the difference.

Comment: yes, so it means these ax have their own display coordinate system , I took "display" coordinate as "figure" coordinate mistakenly,  these ax share the same  "figure" coordinate ? But, what is the differentce between "axes" coordinate and "display" coordinate? the only x,y axis ratio respecitvely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default if the `axes` limits are not specified, `data coordinates` and `axes coordinates` will be the same and are normalized to the limits of 0 to 1 within the limits of the `axes`.

You can set the limits of x and y for your `data coordinates` by these code:

```
ax.set_xlim(min_x, max_x)
ax.set_ylim(min_y, max_y)
```

To see the effect, run this modified code:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
for i, label in enumerate(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i+1)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 8) # data coordinates
    ax.set_ylim(0, 6)
    print(ax.transData.transform([0.5, 0.5]))
    print(ax.transAxes.transform([0.5, 0.5]))
    # the two now print different results

    ax.text(0.1, 0.5, label, transform=ax.transAxes,
            fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')

    ax.text(4.1, 3.5, label+"data", transform=ax.transData,
        fontsize=16, fontweight='bold', va='top')
plt.show()
```

[image: axes-data-coord]

Note that the texts A,B,C,D are now plotted at the new `data coordinates` as labeled on the borders. But these coordinates are actually equivalent to the normalized (0 to 1) of the `axes coordinates`.